# How to model properties that have a Code/Description

Tags: neo4j, data-modeling

I am from a relational background and am new to Neo4J data modeling. I am trying to build a neo4j model to hold information about companies and their relationships.

I have a question on how to setup properties of the Company Node for properties that conform to a set of codes (a Controlled Vocabulary)

So lets say a property of the company node is 'Company Type' and lets say the  possible values are

- Public Limited
- Privately Held
- Limited Liability Partnership
- So on .. (say 50 possible values)

In this case we can simply have Company_Type as a property of the Company Node .. no problems ...

In reality the only difference is things like this have a code and a description, such as :

- 1001 - Public Limited
- 1002 - Privately Held
- 1003 - Limited Liability Partnership

etc ...

I do see the need for the model to be able to support querying by codes and being able to display descriptions.

In the relational world - this is the typical FKey in the company table to a small lookup table ... I am wondering how best to model this in Neo4J

One way i can go about meeting my requirement is to define 2 properties : Company_Type_Code, Company_Type_Description and use them as needed. Is this typically how this is done ?

Or do i Setup 'Company Type' as a node and relating those to company nodes. seems wasteful as millions of rows will point to node 1001 ...

Since this is such a common situation wanted to check what is the best practice for handling the properties that have a Code/Description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most cases you want to model that by having a node for each company type and connect your company nodes to the respective type using a `COMPANY_IS_OF_TYPE` relationship:

```
CREATE (pub:CompanyType{name:'Public Limited',code:1001})
CREATE (priv:CompanyType{name:'Privately Held',code:1002})
CREATE (llp:CompanyType{name:'Limited Lialibty Partnership',code:1003})
CREATE (neo:Company{name:'Neo Technology'})
CREATE (neo)-[:COMPANY_IS_OF_TYPE]->(priv)
```

Since all company types share the same label, you can get them very fast - remember that labels are self-indexed:

```
MATCH (t:CompanyType)<-[:COMPANY_IS_OF_TYPE]-(c)
RETURN t.name, count(c)
```

This gives you some statistics per company type.

Answer (score 2):

Probably the best thing to do would be to store a CompanyType as a type of labeled node.  Then company types could have both the code and the description.  When putting a new company in the database, you'd create a relationship to the right node labeled `:CompanyType` and you're done.

I'm guessing you're going to want to do queries for companies by type, and that's why it's probably going to be a good idea to split it out into a node.  Of course you could keep the code and the description in each node, but this would duplicate a lot of data, and when it came time to look up all companies of a particular type, the query would be slower if you have to scan all `:Company` nodes in order to find the ones where two properties had a certain value.

So you should probably do this:

```
CREATE (:CompanyType { code: "1003", label: "Limited Liability Partnership" });

MATCH (ct:CompanyType { code: "1003" }
WITH ct
CREATE (comp:Company { name: "FooSoft, LLC" })
MERGE (comp)-[:type]->(ct);
```

This method is going to make aggregates easy later, it reduces data duplication, exploits the graph structure, and speeds up queries.   So win/win.

From the RDBMS perspective, you can often think of splitting things out in a separate table as being equivalent to creating a separate node and using a relationship. You can also think of adding things to a node as a property as being very similar to denormalization in an RDBMS.